# How to Name Node Groups

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor

According to the docs when I select some nodes and click `"Add Node Group"` there should be a green bar at the top where I can name the node group, but I don't see that anywhere. I am in cycles. Am I missing it? Also, I can I remove node groups from the list permanently?[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can name your node group after exiting node group edit view, by selecting the Node Group and editing the text in the name box directly, or on the *Properties Tool Shelf > Properties Panel* to the left, while the group is selected.

Your Node Groups will be automatically erased once they have no users in your file, that means it is not used in any material and they have no *Fake Users* (pressing the *F* button to the right of the name.

Have in mind that in Blender data isn't truly deleted until your restart Blender.
That means Materials, Node Groups, Mesh or Object data, and everything else.

For Blender 2.79 and older if you press the delete button it will stick around during that session with a Zero number in front of the name stating that it as no users. It will only be truly deleted after you restart Blender.

For Blender 2.8+ you can check unused data in the *Outliner*, by setting the *Display Mode* to *Orphaned Data* from the dropdown menu in the header. There you will be able to purge unused data manually.

Comment: when I deleted the material completely (so that node group wasn't being used) but the node group still showed up. Do I misunderstand the term users?

Comment: Oh my material isn't being deleted. That's a separate problem

Comment: Have in mind that in blender data isn't truly deleted until your restart Blender. That means Materials, Node Groups, Mesh or Object data, and everything else. If you press the delete button it will stick around during that session with a Zero number in front of the name stating that it as no users. It will only be truly deleted after you restart Blender.