# How to name the node groups?

Tags: materials, node-editor, shaders, shader-nodes

I have a number of materials: M1, M2, M3, and vertex groups V1, V2, V3 on a mesh and would like to apply the materials proportionally to their corresponding vertex groups. In a [previous question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/264241/map-smooth-vertex-group-to-a-vertex-color-in-geometry-nodes) I got an answer how to map the vertex group into an attribute that the shader editor can take.

Now, I would like to mix different materials. What I have been doing so far:

1. for each material, create a node group which takes the texture mapping and exposes the BSDF output
2. create a meta-material, where I would input the node groups and mix them with the mix shader.

Problem:
The node groups created have names like `NodeGroup.001` which makes it hard to distinguish different materials from each other. In the meta-material shader, it's possible to rename the group node, but it doesn't change the name of the underlying node group, so if I were to use it elsewhere, I still need to remember what `NodeGroup.042` corresponds to:

[image: node group naming]

Note that even though `NodeGroup` node was renamed to `rock`, it still appears as `NodeGroup` in the `Add > Group` option.

Questions:

1. is there a way to rename the underlying node group, as opposed to its corresponding node in the meta-material?
2. isn't there a better workflow for what I'm doing? Ideally I would not have to create node groups at all, I'd rather have a version of Mix Shader that takes the whole materials (which can be easily named) instead.

I saw [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/54001/how-to-name-node-groups), which only answers the question of naming the node group in the outer group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Nodes have a *name* (unique - you shouldn't need to worry about that if you don't plan on using the python scripting API) and a *label* which can be shared among many different nodes. Node groups are "instanced" via node group nodes, which have a Node Group data block as a mandatory parameter. Here you re-labeled the *node*, not the underlying *node group*. Click in the field inside the node group to rename the underlying node group.

Alternatively open the right hand side panel with <kbd>N</kbd> or clicking on the arrow in the top right of the node editor, expand the *Properties* subpanel and change the name there.

[image]

2. No, it is not possible to access external material outputs inside other materials.

Comment: to clarify for posterity: by "click in the field inside the node group" you mean to change the  text that's "My Node Group" on the screenshot. I assumed that by changing that I would be changing which node group I'm using, but it's working as you suggested, only changing the name of the underlying node group. Thanks!

Comment: Ups right yeah I meant clicking on the white label on black background, not the material icon with the dropdown arrow. Cheers